# AVG*COUNT return a float value

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does this SELECT statment return a float value? How can I cast it into an integer?

```
select area.name, coalesce(((avg(recording.length)*count(recording.length))/1000/60),0)
```

Comment: AVG*COUNT is the same as SUM, why don't you just use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result of `avg(recording.length)*count(recording.length)` isn't a multiple of `60000`, you'll get a fraction when you do that division. You can use `ROUND()` to round this to the nearest integer.

Also, since the average is the sum divided by the count, multiplying by the count just returns the sum. You can just use that directly.

```
SELECT area.name, coalesce(ROUND(SUM(recording.length)/1000/60)), 0)
```

Comment: Can you even get a NULL from a SUM?  Not sure that COALESCE does anything here.

Comment: @LukStorms He didn't show the whole query, but I assume there'a a `LEFT JOIN` with `recording`, it will return `NULL` if there are no matching rows.

Comment: Thx. And I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048343/) about SUM returning NULL's and why.  So it's possible in MySql, I just wasn't aware of it yet.